# Which XCode supports iOS 14.5.1 - the minimum version for AirTag support?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina, ios14, airtag

It looks like the latest XCode 12.5 on Catalina does not support iOS 14.5.1 yet...

Which XCode supports iOS 14.5.1 - the minimum version for AirTag support? Is this available for Catalina, or is one forced to upgrade to Big Sur?

---

Note, the beta version of XCode is not listed as available for download. Also iOS 14.5.1 is not a beta iOS.

Comment: What do you mean by "AirTag support"? Are you talking about `Nearby Interaction` or do you want to use your AirTags as a user?

Comment: AirTag requires iOS 14.5.1 - however XCode does not support that yet

Comment: It appears that one has to upgrade to Big Sur to have an XCode that supports the minimum iOS for AirTag :(

Comment: AirTag actually requires iOS 14.5 at minimum, not 14.5.1. https://www.macrumors.com/guide/ios-14-5-features/

Comment: I had 14.5 but airtag would not let me install unless i update to 14.5.1

Answer (score 0):

There weren't any sizeable changes in the SDK to warrant a new Xcode release. That would make it the Xcode 12.5 betas and final release, which dropped support for Catalina.

You can see Xcode version history at: https://xcodereleases.com/